# Segmentation fault (core dumped) while building SciPy from source

Tags: python, linux, scipy

I tried building the SciPy library from source on my Linux machine by following the steps mentioned in [this](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/dev/contributor/quickstart_ubuntu.html#quickstart-ubuntu) tutorial.

In the 13th step, when trying to test the build using
`python3 runtests.py -v`, a segmentation fault is thrown.

I'm using a conda virtual environment called `scipydev`

Here's the related log:

```
scipy/sparse/linalg/_isolve/tests/test_gcrotmk.py .......                                                                                                                                           [ 54%]
scipy/sparse/linalg/_isolve/tests/test_iterative.py ...........................xxxxX............................                                                                                    [ 55%]
scipy/sparse/linalg/_isolve/tests/test_lgmres.py ........                                                                                                                                           [ 55%]
scipy/sparse/linalg/_isolve/tests/test_lsmr.py ...............                                                                                                                                      [ 55%]
scipy/sparse/linalg/_isolve/tests/test_lsqr.py .....                                                                                                                                                [ 55%]
scipy/sparse/linalg/_isolve/tests/test_minres.py .......                                                                                                                                            [ 55%]
scipy/sparse/linalg/_isolve/tests/test_utils.py .                                                                                                                                                   [ 55%]
scipy/sparse/linalg/tests/test_expm_multiply.py .................                                                                                                                                   [ 55%]
scipy/sparse/linalg/tests/test_interface.py ..............                                                                                                                                          [ 55%]
scipy/sparse/linalg/tests/test_matfuncs.py ............................Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x00007f9bed60f740 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/bharath/scipy/scipy/build/testenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/linalg/_basic.py", line 223 in solve
  File "/home/bharath/scipy/scipy/build/testenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/_matfuncs.py", line 708 in _solve_P_Q
  File "/home/bharath/scipy/scipy/build/testenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/_matfuncs.py", line 672 in _expm
  File "/home/bharath/scipy/scipy/build/testenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/_matfuncs.py", line 590 in expm
  File "/home/bharath/scipy/scipy/build/testenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/tests/test_matfuncs.py", line 516 in test_pascal
  File "/home/bharath/anaconda3/envs/scipydev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/python.py", line 192 in pytest_pyfunc_call
  File "/home/bharath/anaconda3/envs/scipydev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "/home/bharath/anaconda3/envs/scipydev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "/home/bharath/anaconda3/envs/scipydev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "/home/bharath/anaconda3/envs/scipydev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/python.py", line 1718 in runtest
  File "/home/bharath/anaconda3/envs/scipydev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 168 in pytest_runtest_call
  File "/home/bharath/anaconda3/envs/scipydev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "/home/bharath/anaconda3/envs/scipydev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "/home/bharath/anaconda3/envs/scipydev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "/home/bharath/anaconda3/envs/scipydev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 261 in <lambda>
  File "/home/bharath/anaconda3/envs/scipydev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 340 in from_call
  File "/home/bharath/anaconda3/envs/scipydev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 260 in call_runtest_hook
  File "/home/bharath/anaconda3/envs/scipydev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 221 in call_and_report
  File "/home/bharath/anaconda3/envs/scipydev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 132 in runtestprotocol
  File "/home/bharath/anaconda3/envs/scipydev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 113 in pytest_runtest_protocol
  File "/home/bharath/anaconda3/envs/scipydev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "/home/bharath/anaconda3/envs/scipydev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "/home/bharath/anaconda3/envs/scipydev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "/home/bharath/anaconda3/envs/scipydev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 347 in pytest_runtestloop
  File "/home/bharath/anaconda3/envs/scipydev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "/home/bharath/anaconda3/envs/scipydev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "/home/bharath/anaconda3/envs/scipydev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "/home/bharath/anaconda3/envs/scipydev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 322 in _main
  File "/home/bharath/anaconda3/envs/scipydev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 268 in wrap_session
  File "/home/bharath/anaconda3/envs/scipydev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 315 in pytest_cmdline_main
  File "/home/bharath/anaconda3/envs/scipydev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "/home/bharath/anaconda3/envs/scipydev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "/home/bharath/anaconda3/envs/scipydev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "/home/bharath/anaconda3/envs/scipydev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 165 in main
  File "/home/bharath/scipy/scipy/build/testenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_testutils.py", line 69 in __call__
  File "runtests.py", line 334 in main
  File "runtests.py", line 612 in <module>
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I suspect the LAPACK or BLAS libraries might be causing this but I'm not really sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Python: 3.8

Numpy: 1.22.2

Latest commit: 31ed6bc

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily an answer but maybe a lead.

When building python packages from source, some code needs C compilers, it is important you check what you have and what is required before installing, then get the necessary compiler version.

It's a rare case, but still worth a shot.